# How to create a simple reverse proxy exposing multiple services under single port

Tags: networking, proxy, socat

The common problem with microservices is that developing them can be cumbersome if you use AJAX and try to read input from multiuple hosts/ports (due to cross domain requests).

I am looking for a very simple solution that would work with linux (preferably using python or socat) where I can chain few hosts/ports under a single port.

```
host1:port1/service1 and host2:port2/service2 ... -> localhost:port
```

All remote hosts/ports can be accessed from the same localhost:port.

The requests should be forwarded based on the paths:

```
localhost:port/service1 -> host1:port1/service1 
localhost:port/service2 -> host2:port2/service2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a http reverse proxy will do , like this apache config with mod_proxy enabled .

```
Listen port
ProxyPass /service1 http://host1:port1/service1
ProxyPass /service2 http://host1:port1/service2
```

---

dispatching localhost:port/service1 and localhost:port/service2 involves knowledge of http protocol . the service is not distinguished on the tcp layer , but a http get request . i am not aware of that socat can handle this .